# Why the port of confignode cannot be used after metrics are enabled in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

The port cannot be successfully opened after `metrics` are enabled in `iotdb-confignode` of Version 1.1 in Apache IoTDB, has anyone encountered this problem, and how to solve it? The port for datanodes in IoTDB can be successfully used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is port 9091 occupied on the same server of Apache IoTDB? If there is a confignode and a datanode in one IoTDB, you need to change the ports of their two configuration files. Do not use 9091 for both kinds of nodes, or the port settings will conflict with each other.